# java.security.NoSuchProviderException: no such provider: nCipherKM

Tags: java, wildfly, hsm

We are trying to connect to an HSM. However even after we add nCipher to the list of providers and restart wildfly, it is still giving this error upon deployment.

Any idea why it's not detecting it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the nCipherKM in `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext` folder for JDK or `$JAVA_HOME/lib/ext` for JRE.

Reassure that you have both jcecsp and javasp bundles installed.

Hardserver configuration needs to be done properly to accept connections at 9000 and 9001 locally.

Security world needs to be created/imported. You can check that using `nfkminfo` command.

Restart the hardserver if you had to do any configuration changes.